# Anything like Watin available for C++?

Tags: c++, screen-scraping, watin

I'm wondering if there are any projects like Watin available for C++ (on Windows), or if I just have to use QtWebkit.

Does anyone know of any good IE automation libraries that work well in C++ and provide a nice layer above MS's WebBrowser control?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [IE automation library like Watin/Watir for C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8691744/ie-automation-library-like-watin-watir-for-c)

Comment: @paulsm4: That new one should be marking as a dupe of this preexisting one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using Mozilla's Gecko/FireFox engine in C++.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Embedding_Mozilla

Answer (score 0):

You can use IRobotSoft Visual Web Scraper.  It has an ActiveX control for C++ in its package.

Comment: ActiveX is not really optimized for C++.  After all, you can control the WebBrowser control through COM as well.

Comment: The IRobotSoft ActiveX provides a high level interface above WebBrowser control. The efficiency of the control does not lie in the ActiveX interfaces, but in its data processing capability underlying the interfaces. The control is written in C++, so I believe it is very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

For automation take a look at [**VOLE** - A Neat C++ COM/Automation Driver](http://vole.sourceforge.net/).

For C++ Web development see:

1. [**CppCMS** — C++ Web Development Framework](http://cppcms.sourceforge.net/wikipp/en/page/main)
2. [**Wt** - A C++ Web Toolkit](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt)

Answer (score 0):

You can and should also look at alternatives like [Watir](http://watir.com/) and [Selinium](http://seleniumhq.org/).