# IE automation library like Watin/Watir for C++

Tags: c++, windows, internet-explorer, screen-scraping

Does anyone know of any good IE automation libraries (similar to Watin) that work well in C++ and provide a nice layer above MS's WebBrowser control?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Anything like Watin available for C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564101/anything-like-watin-available-for-c)

Answer (score 0):

You might look at IRobotX ActiveX control from irobotsoft.

Answer (score -1):

You might be interested in the project that INSPIRED Watin - Watir:

http://watir.com/

Watir is Ruby (not C++) ... but it's open source, it's cross platform, and it supports other browsers besides IE.  And it doesn't require .Net :)